# How do I install nose on a Mac for python 3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, osx-mavericks, nose

I used easy_install to install nose on my Mac (OS Mavericks). It works fine with the default python 2.7 installation.

If I run nosetests on a module using python 3, it fails to find the imports. What do I need to know and do, to use nose for python 3 as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the steps that I found to work. Thanks, for the parts contributed by MattDMo.

```
# use python3 to unstall pip3
sudo python3 get-pip.py
which python3
# ls -l on the result of which to find the target of the link
# Using the path to the target (directory), set up links to pip3, pip3.3
ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip3
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pip3.3 /usr/local/bin/pip3.3
# install nose for python3
# and set a link to the installation
sudo pip3 install nose
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/nosetests-3.3 /usr/local/bin/nosetests-3.3
```

Answer (score 9):

The best way to handle installation (and removal) of third-party packages is to use [`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/). First, download [`get-pip.py`](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) and save it someplace. Navigate to that folder in Terminal and enter

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

to install it for Python 3. I'd recommend running

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

as well to install it for Python 2, as `easy_install` is deprecated.

Once you have `pip` installed, you should have access to `pip3` or `pip-3.3` - check the installation directory to see exactly which scripts were installed. Assuming you have the command `pip3`, you can now run

```
sudo pip3 install nose
```

and it will install `nose` and any dependencies in your Python 3 `site-packages` folder, as well as a `nosetests` executable in your Python installation's `bin` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The get-pip.py link looks like it just gives some kind of ascii or base64 in the browser. Maybe with installation instructions for pip I could make some progress.

Comment: I did File, Save as... using Chrome on the get-pip.py link. Ran sudo python3 get-pip.py, as well as sudo python get-pip.py.. The python3 showed an installation of pip and setuptools. The other only pip.

Comment: ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep pip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel       204 Jan 23 20:25 pip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel       204 Jan 23 20:25 pip2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   wheel       204 Jan 23 20:25 pip2.7